# why select range and popup window can not work together in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having this html structure to popup a new window and to select everything inside the pre tags:

```
<a href="#" onclick="popup(this)">Open Ppup</a> 
<a class="selectable" href='javascript:fnSelect("a1")'>[Select All Code]</a>

<pre class="CodeBlock linenums" id="a1">
line 1<br />
line 2<br />
line 3
</pre>

<a href="#" onclick="popup(this)">Open Popup</a> 
<a class="selectable" href='javascript:fnSelect("a2")'>[Select All Code]</a>

<pre class="CodeBlock linenums" id="a2">
 line 4<br />
 line 5<br />
 line 6
 </pre>
```

The js for the popup:

```
function popup(obj)
{
var myHtml = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8">   <title>Popup</title></head><body>' +
  $(obj).next('.CodeBlock').html() +
  '</body></html>';

  var generator = window.open('','name','height=400,width=500');
  generator.document.body.innerHTML = myHtml;
}
```

And the js for the selection:

```
function fnSelect(objId) {
    fnDeSelect();
    if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(objId));
    range.select();

    }
    else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(objId));
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    }
}

function fnDeSelect() {
    if (document.selection) document.selection.empty(); 
    else if (window.getSelection)
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
```

It seems that both anchors can not be together in the html. If together, the popup does not work anymore ( at least it gives me *undefined* as content).
If i skip the anchor with **[Select All Code]** the popup works fine.
See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ax8Hz/47/

My question: why does the popup not work anymore when the other anchor (SelectAllCode) is also in the html?
How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function popup(obj)
{
  var myHtml = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Popup</title></head><body>' +
      $(obj).nextAll('.CodeBlock').first().html() +
      '</body></html>';

  var generator = window.open('','name','height=400,width=500');
  generator.document.body.innerHTML = myHtml;
}
```

`.next()` looks at the next element, NOT the next element with that class, so use `nextAll` and `first()` to essentially do the same thing

Comment: Awesome! It works perfect. I now do understand the issue. Thanks for the solution